# Using of a data tree in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, datagrid, dojo, contextmenu

I'd like to create a page on wich one I'll set a data view and/or a datagrid to display some hierarchical information on it. Also, I'd like to have a contextuel menu (right click) on it.

It's my first time I use Drupal. Previously, I was using the toolkit Dojo for creating this menu tree. However, I saw that Dojo is not really supported by Drupal.

Could you help me? Waht is the best solution to create such menu tree/datagrid on Durpal?

Thanks you very much,

Bat

Answer (score 1):

You have to make changes in the theme of your drupal site for data view and/or a datagrid display

For contextual menu visit: http://drupal.org/project/vbo_contextmenu

Cheers!!
vivek